# Old FORTRAN Namelist Compiler (gfortran) Flag?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm currently in the process of upgrading an old program written in FORTRAN and I'm trying to get it to compile using `gfortran`.  I can get it to build, however the program now chokes on the namelists that it is reading in.

An example of a namelist that came with the program is shown below.  It cannot correctly read this file due to the space between the variable name and the parenthesis.  Since these files are very large, is there anyway I can tell `gfortran` to expect an older namelist format?

```
&<NAME>
 <VARNAME> (1) = 0,
 <VARNAME> (2) = -1e-13,
 <VARNAME> (3) = 0.2983
&End
```

If not, I can resort to doing a search/replace but I'd rather not mess with the data and just have the code successfully read it in.

Comment: I would just remove all spaces with sed.

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/ (/(/g' test.nml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namelist is quite complicated, as you can tell from the fact that there are 92 namelist test cases in the gfortran testsuite.

gfortran has no option to do what you ask.  You will probably have to remove the blanks by hand or by sed, like Vladimir F suggested.

I might add that blanks in the subobject designator (the varname(i) part) are explicitly forbidden in the F2003 standard 10.10.1.1:

"In the input record, each object name or subobject designator may be preceded and followed by one or more optional blanks but shall not contain embedded blanks."

so this is unlikely to be changed in a future version of gfortran.